# How to display and calculate random numbers in a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, random, jlabel

I am trying to create a program where I could calculate 2 randomly generated numbers and display them in a `JLabel`. The program is successfully displaying random numbers in a `JLabel` but it only calculates the first set of numbers that have been generated.

I want it to be able to calculate all the sets of numbers being generated randomly.

```
Random dice = new Random();
boolean solution;
JLabel num1,num2,checker;
int calculation;

public void repeatLoop() {
    switch(calculation) {
    case 1:
        int addition1 = Integer.valueOf(num1.getText()) + Integer.valueOf(num2.getText());
        break;
    case 2:
        num1.setText("");
        num2.setText("");
        break;
    case 3:
        num1.setText(String.valueOf(1 + dice.nextInt(6)));
        num2.setText(String.valueOf(1 + dice.nextInt(6)));
        break;
    }
}

public JLabel checkerLabel() {
    JLabel checker = new JLabel("");
    checker.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
    checker.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    checker.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    checker.setBounds(163, 21, 109, 23);
    contentPane.add(checker);
    return checker;
}

public addFrame() {
    JLabel num1 = new JLabel("3");
    num1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    num1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    num1.setBounds(122, 101, 63, 32);
    contentPane.add(num1);

    JLabel num2 = new JLabel("4");
    num2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    num2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    num2.setBounds(268, 101, 63, 32);
    contentPane.add(num2);

    this.num1 = num1;
    this.num2 = num2;
    calculation = 3;
    int addition1 = Integer.valueOf(num1.getText()) + Integer.valueOf(num2.getText());
    JLabel addOperation = new JLabel("+");
    addOperation.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    addOperation.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    addOperation.setBounds(195, 101, 63, 32);
    contentPane.add(addOperation);

    this.checker = checkerLabel();

    textField1 = new JTextField();
    textField1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    textField1.setBounds(163, 155, 120, 32);
    contentPane.add(textField1);
    textField1.setColumns(10);

    JButton checkBtn1 = new JButton("Check");
    checkBtn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            final int addition2 = addition1;
            int ansUser = Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText());
            if(addition2 == ansUser) {
                solution = true;
            } else {
                solution = false;
            }
            if(solution == true) {
                checker.setText("CORRECT");
                checker.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
            } else {
                checker.setText("WRONG");
                checker.setForeground(Color.RED);
            }
            textField1.setText("");
            calculation = 1;
            calculation = 2;
            repeatLoop();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few logic bugs in your code. I believe I have fixed them in the below code.

I suggest that you run the below code to make sure that it behaves the way that you want. If it does then compare it with your code to see the differences. There aren't many. Here is a summary:

1. I made `addition1` a class member.
2. I added a single `break` statement in the `switch` statement in method `repeatLoop`.
3. I changed the last few lines of method `actionPerformed`.

Finally, I suggest that you run your original code with a debugger to see why your code has logic problems.

Here is the code.

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class addFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField1;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    addFrame frame = new addFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    Random dice = new Random();
    boolean solution;
    JLabel num1, num2, checker;
    int calculation;
    int addition1;

    public void repeatLoop() {
        switch (calculation) {
            case 1:
                addition1 = Integer.valueOf(num1.getText()) + Integer.valueOf(num2.getText());
                break;
            case 2:
                num1.setText("");
                num2.setText("");
            case 3:
                num1.setText(String.valueOf(1 + dice.nextInt(6)));
                num2.setText(String.valueOf(1 + dice.nextInt(6)));
        }
    }

    public JLabel checkerLabel() {
        JLabel checker = new JLabel("");
        checker.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 13));
        checker.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        checker.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        checker.setBounds(163, 21, 109, 23);
        contentPane.add(checker);
        return checker;
    }

    public addFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel title3 = new JLabel("ADDITION");
        title3.setForeground(Color.RED);
        title3.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        title3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        title3.setBounds(108, 47, 224, 32);
        contentPane.add(title3);

        JLabel num1 = new JLabel("3");
        num1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        num1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        num1.setBounds(122, 101, 63, 32);
        contentPane.add(num1);

        JLabel num2 = new JLabel("4");
        num2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        num2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        num2.setBounds(268, 101, 63, 32);
        contentPane.add(num2);

        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2;
        calculation = 3;
        addition1 = Integer.valueOf(num1.getText()) + Integer.valueOf(num2.getText());
        JLabel addOperation = new JLabel("+");
        addOperation.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        addOperation.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        addOperation.setBounds(195, 101, 63, 32);
        contentPane.add(addOperation);

        this.checker = checkerLabel();

        textField1 = new JTextField();
        textField1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        textField1.setBounds(163, 155, 120, 32);
        contentPane.add(textField1);
        textField1.setColumns(10);

        JButton checkBtn1 = new JButton("Check");
        checkBtn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                final int addition2 = addition1;
                int ansUser = Integer.parseInt(textField1.getText());
                if (addition2 == ansUser) {
                    solution = true;
                }
                else {
                    solution = false;
                }
                if (solution == true) {
                    checker.setText("CORRECT");
                    checker.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                }
                else {
                    checker.setText("WRONG");
                    checker.setForeground(Color.RED);
                }
                textField1.setText("");
                calculation = 2;
                repeatLoop();
                calculation = 1;
                repeatLoop();
            }
        });
        checkBtn1.setBounds(183, 211, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(checkBtn1);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Arnulfo890 I still recommend that you do as I suggested in my answer, namely run your original code with a debugger in order to understand why it does not behave the way you want it to. And thank you for accepting my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add `break` after each case in your `switch(calculation)`  structure.

Try to modify the switch statement as:

```
switch(calculation) {
   case 1:
        int addition1 = Integer.valueOf(num1.getText()) + Integer.valueOf(num2.getText());
        break;
   case 2:
        num1.setText("");
        num2.setText("");
        break;
   case 3:
        num1.setText(String.valueOf(1 + dice.nextInt(6)));
        num2.setText(String.valueOf(1 + dice.nextInt(6)));
        break;
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks, I modify my switch statement now, but I'm still stuck at the calculation of the first set of numbers even though the JLabel is already displaying a different number :(  btw sorry if my code is messy